# Extract image from PDF using C#

Tags: c#, pdf, image-processing, ghostscript

I have an issue with extracting Image from PDF. I tried using GhostScript but the image is extracted with pixelized Teeth like lined at the objects edges. Nothing I tried improved it. When increasing the DPI, extracted images are too big. Something is reducing image quality when extracted.

I would appreciate anyone to recommend a package to perform such an operation - either paid or free.

Comment: I have good experience with PdfSharp. Example source code can be found here: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1.

Comment: I have used PdfSharp for my project as well

Comment: Actually any general-purpose PDF library should allow you to extract embedded bitmaps in their natural resolution.

Answer (score 2):

There are enough general-purpose PDF libraries out there that can be used to extract images from PDFs. Not all of them offer a simple way to do so.

As one of the developers of [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/), I can recommend it for the task.

Here is a sample that shows how to extract all images from a PDF:

```
static void ExtractImagesFromPdfPages()
{
    string path = "";
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(path))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Pages.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pdf.Pages[i].Images.Count; j++)
            {
                string imageName = string.Format("page{0}-image{1}", i, j);
                string imagePath = pdf.Pages[i].Images[j].Save(imageName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The library won't resample images. It will save them exactly the same as in PDF.

Comment: Does `pdf.Pages[i].Images[j]` return all the images from the resources of the page or does it return the images used on the page? The latter would not necessarily include all images from the resources but additionally inline images and images from used xobjects.

Comment: @mkl It returns all images (inlined and not)

Comment: Ah, that's good. Merely the images from the page resources can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a .NETFramework C# console app to extract and display all of the image data from a pdf document.

Using [itext7 v8.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7) and [photo.exif v1.1.16](https://www.nuget.org/packages/photo.exif) nuget packages.

The image objects are retrieved exactly as they are in the PDF without modification, compression, etc.

```
using iText.Commons.Utils;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Xobject;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = "C:\\Path\\To\\Pdf\\Document.pdf";
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

        WriteHeading($"Extracting Data for: {fileInfo.Name}");

        using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileInfo))
        using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
        {
            var documentInfo = pdfDocument.GetDocumentInfo();

            WriteLines(
                JsonUtil.SerializeToString(new
                {
                    fileInfo.Name,
                    fileInfo.FullName,
                    fileInfo.LastWriteTime,
                    fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc,
                    Attributes = fileInfo.Attributes.ToString(),
                    fileInfo.CreationTime,
                    fileInfo.CreationTimeUtc,
                    fileInfo.Length,
                    Author = documentInfo.GetAuthor(),
                    Creator = documentInfo.GetCreator(),
                    Keywords = documentInfo.GetKeywords(),
                    Producer = documentInfo.GetProducer(),
                    Subject = documentInfo.GetSubject(),
                    Title = documentInfo.GetTitle(),
                    NumberOfPages = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(),
                    NumberOfPdfObjects = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPdfObjects(),
                    PdfVersion = pdfDocument
                       .GetPdfVersion()
                       .ToPdfName()
                       .GetValue()
                }),
                ""
            );

            // List of Images found in the PDF file.
            var images = GetAndPrintImageInformation(pdfDocument);
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                image.Save("C:\\Path\\To\\Save\\To");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static List<Image> GetAndPrintImageInformation(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
    {
        var images = new List<Image>();

        for (var i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPdfObjects(); i++)
        {
            var pdfObject = pdfDocument.GetPdfObject(i);
            if (pdfObject == null)
                continue;

            if (!pdfObject.IsStream())
                continue;

            var pdfStream = pdfObject as PdfStream;
            if (!pdfStream.ContainsKey(PdfName.Subtype))
                continue;

            var subType = pdfStream.GetAsName(PdfName.Subtype).GetValue();
            if (subType != PdfName.Image.GetValue()
                && subType != PdfName.ImageMask.GetValue()
                && subType != PdfName.StampImage.GetValue()
            ) continue;

            var imageObj = PdfXObject.MakeXObject(pdfStream) as PdfImageXObject;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageObj.GetImageBytes()))
            {
                var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                images.Add(image);

                var data = new photo.exif.Parser().Parse(ms);
                var exifDataJson = JsonUtil.SerializeToString(data);

                WriteLines(
                    $"Image Type: {imageObj.IdentifyImageType()}",
                    $"File Extension: {imageObj.IdentifyImageFileExtension()}",
                    $"Dimensions: {image.Width}w X {image.Height}h",
                    $"Tag: {image.Tag}",
                    $"ExifData: {exifDataJson}",
                    ""
                );
            }
        }

        return images;
    }

    static void WriteHeading(string heading)
    {
        WriteLines(
            heading,
            new string(
                Enumerable.Range(0, heading.Length)
                    .Select(x => '=')
                    .ToArray()
            )
        );
    }

    static void WriteLines(params object[] lines)
    {
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Extracting Data for: Document.pdf
=================================
{
  "Name": "Document.pdf",
  "FullName": "C:\\Path\\To\\Pdf\\Document.pdf",
  "LastWriteTime": "2020-01-29T14:49:16.9118875+00:00",
  "LastWriteTimeUtc": "2020-01-29T14:49:16.9118875Z",
  "Attributes": "Archive",
  "CreationTime": "2020-01-29T01:06:10.1240743+00:00",
  "CreationTimeUtc": "2020-01-29T01:06:10.1240743Z",
  "Length": 354600,
  "Author": "James",
  "Creator": "Microsoftr Word 2010",
  "Producer": "Microsoftr Word 2010",
  "NumberOfPages": 1,
  "NumberOfPdfObjects": 59,
  "PdfVersion": "1.5"
}

Image Type: JPEG
File Extension: jpg
Dimensions: 2012w X 622h
Tag:
ExifData: [
  {
    "Title": "ChrominanceTable",
    "Description": "Chrominance table. The luminance table and the ...",
    "Id": 20625,
    "Length": 128,
    "Value": 9
  },
  {
    "Title": "LuminanceTable",
    "Description": "Luminance table. The luminance table and the ...",
    "Id": 20624,
    "Length": 128,
    "Value": 8
  }
]

Image Type: JPEG
File Extension: jpg
Dimensions: 480w X 640h
Tag:
ExifData: [
  {
    "Title": "ChrominanceTable",
    "Description": "Chrominance table. The luminance table and the ...",
    "Id": 20625,
    "Length": 128,
    "Value": 9
  },
  {
    "Title": "LuminanceTable",
    "Description": "Luminance table. The luminance table and the ...",
    "Id": 20624,
    "Length": 128,
    "Value": 8
  }
]

Image Type: JPEG
File Extension: jpg
Dimensions: 370w X 165h
Tag:
ExifData: [
  {
    "Title": "LuminanceTable",
    "Description": "Luminance table. The luminance table and the ...",
    "Id": 20624,
    "Length": 128,
    "Value": 8
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Core version of iTextSharp is incomplete. I tried for hours without success. I had success using the free package [PdfPig](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig).

```
public static void ExtractImagesWithPdfPig(byte[] pdfBytes)
{
    using var document = PdfDocument.Open(pdfBytes);
    foreach (var page in document.GetPages())
        foreach (var pdfImage in page.GetImages())
        {
            var bytes = TryGetImage(pdfImage);
            using var mem = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            Image img;
            try
            {
                // Ensure data is valid 
                img = Image.FromStream(mem);
            }
            catch (Exception) { continue; }

            // TODO : Do what you want with the image or bytes

            // Free code : get the ideal file extension
            var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().First(c => c.FormatID == img.RawFormat.Guid);
            var extension = codec.FilenameExtension.Split(';').First().TrimStart('*', '.').ToLower();
        }

    byte[] TryGetImage(IPdfImage image)
    {
        if (image.TryGetPng(out var bytes))
            return bytes;

        if (image.TryGetBytes(out var iroBytes))
            return iroBytes.ToArray();

        return image.RawBytes.ToArray();
    }
}
```